# Ubuntu 16.04 MariaDb no sample configurations

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ubuntu-16.04, my.cnf

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server (VPS), I installed MariaDb 10.1 on it ([did it like the doc said](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=bme&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=xenial--ubuntu_xenial&version=10.1)). I would like to configure the database server, so innodb can use 2-4GB memory, so I tried to find the sample `my.cnf`'s in `/usr/share/mysql/` but not a single one is there ([only these](http://pastebin.com/WysnWhXt)). Where can I find the sample configurations and how can I make them the actual? I read the `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/` dir should contain a `mysqld.cnf`, but for me there are only these files:

```
50-client.cnf  50-mysql-clients.cnf  50-mysqld_safe.cnf  50-server.cnf  50-server.cnf.backup
```

Which one is active? My guess is none.

I don't need anything special, that is why I wanted to just actualize the `my-huge.cnf` and be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy one of those to `/etc/my.cnf`.  Without the file being there, you (probably) have no config other than built-in defaults.

Show us the contents for further critique.

Comment: Most likely `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Answer (score -1):

How much RAM do you have?

The most important setting for the server `my.cnf` is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  If you have more than 4GB of RAM, set it to about 70% of available RAM.  If you have less than 4GB, use some smaller percentage.  Swapping is terribly bad for performance.

Comment: The server has 12GB of RAM, but I am not the only one on it and other processes need a significant amount of ram too. I develop on Windows now and I used the sample configuration for MariaDB, it worked perfectly, yet with the install on the server it has terrible performance due to the misconfigured MariaDB.

Comment: Is there any evidence of swapping?